# Human Elf Cyberdemon Balrog inheritance

Tags: c++

Forgive me for not splitting into different files. This is one of the Human Elf Cyberdemon Balrog assignments. My output is correct except that Human and Elf, which are Creatures, have their names correctly displayed, but Cyberdemon and Balrog, which are Demons, have their names displayed as Demon.

I also need to make the base class's getSpecies() function a pure virtual function but that gives me errors.

Incidentally, I deleted the Cyberdemon class's getDamage() (which I'm supposed to) and the output corrected from Demon to Cyberdemon. So I'm confused.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

    class Creature
    {
    private:
        int strength;
        int hitpoints;


    public:
        Creature()
        {
            strength = 10;
            hitpoints = 10;
        }



        Creature(int newStrength, int newHitpoints)
        {
            strength = newStrength;
            newHitpoints = newHitpoints;
        }



        int getStrength()
        {
            return strength;
        }



        int getHitpoints()
        {
            return hitpoints;
        }



        void setStrength(int newStrength)
        {
            strength = newStrength;
        }



        void setHitpoints(int newHitpoints)
        {
            hitpoints = newHitpoints;
        }


        virtual string getSpecies()
        {
            return "unknownnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn";
        }



        int getDamage()
        {
            int damage;
            damage = (rand() % strength) + 1;
            cout << "The " << getSpecies() << " attacks for " << damage << " points!" << endl;
            return damage;
        }
    };




    class Demon : public Creature
    {
    public:
        Demon()
        {
            setStrength(10);
            setHitpoints(10);
        }



        Demon(int newStrength, int newHitpoints)
        {
            setStrength(newStrength);
            setHitpoints(newHitpoints);
        }



        string getSpecies()
        {
            return "Demon";
        }



        int getDamage()
        {
            int damage;
            Demon demon(getStrength(), getHitpoints());
            damage = Creature::getDamage();
            if ((rand() % 100) < 25)
            {
                damage += 50;
                cout << "Demonic attack inflicts 50 additional damage points!" << endl;
            }
            return damage;
        }
    };









    class Human : public Creature
    {
    public:
        Human()
        {
            setStrength(10);
            setHitpoints(10);
        }



        Human(int newStrength, int newHitpoints)
        {
            setStrength(newStrength);
            setHitpoints(newHitpoints);
        }



        string getSpecies()
        {
            return "Human";
        }


        /*int getDamage()
        {
            int damage;
        Creature human(getStrength(), getHitpoints());
            damage = Creature::getDamage();
            return damage;
        }*/
    };









    class Elf : public Creature
    {
    public:
        Elf()
        {
            setStrength(10);
            setHitpoints(10);
        }



        Elf(int newStrength, int newHitpoints)
        {
            setStrength(newStrength);
            setHitpoints(newHitpoints);
        }



        string getSpecies()
        {
            return "Elf";
        }



        int getDamage()
        {
            int damage;
            Creature elf(getStrength(), getHitpoints());

            damage = Creature::getDamage();

            if ((rand() % 100) < 50) //elf extra damage chance
            {
                cout << "\nMagical attack inflicts " << damage << " additional damage points!" << endl;
                damage = damage * 2;
            }
            return damage;
        }
    };










    class Cyberdemon : public Demon
    {
    public:
        Cyberdemon()
        {
            setStrength(10);
            setHitpoints(10);
        }



        Cyberdemon(int newStrength, int newHitpoints)
        {
            setStrength(newStrength);
            setHitpoints(newHitpoints);
        }



        string getSpecies()
        {
            return "Cyberdemon";
        }



        /*int getDamage()
        {
            int damage;
            Demon cyberdemon(getStrength(), getHitpoints());

            damage = cyberdemon.getDamage();
            return damage;
        }*/
    };








    class Balrog : public Demon
    {
    public:
        Balrog()
        {
            setStrength(10);
            setHitpoints(10);
        }



        Balrog(int newStrength, int newHitpoints)
        {
            setStrength(newStrength);
            setHitpoints(newHitpoints);
        }



        string getSpecies()
        {
            return "Balrog";
        }



        int getDamage()
        {
            int damage;
            int second_damage;
            Demon balrog(getStrength(), getHitpoints());

            damage = balrog.getDamage();
            second_damage = (rand() % getStrength()) + 1;

            cout << "Balrog speed attack inflicts " << second_damage << " additional damage points!\n";

            damage = damage + second_damage;
            return damage;
        }
    };












    int main()
    {
        srand(time(0));

        Human h1;
        Elf e1;
        Cyberdemon c1;
        Balrog b1;

        Human h(20, 30);
        Elf e(40, 50);
        Cyberdemon c(60, 70);
        Balrog b(80, 90);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        cout << "default Human strength/hitpoints: " << h1.getStrength() << "/" << h1.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << "default Elf strength/hitpoints: " << e1.getStrength() << "/" << e1.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << "default Cyberdemon strength/hitpoints: " << c1.getStrength() << "/" << c1.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << "default Balrog strength/hitpoints: " << b1.getStrength() << "/" << b1.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << "non-default Human strength/hitpoints: " << h.getStrength() << "/" << h.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << "non-default Elf strength/hitpoints: " << e.getStrength() << "/" << e.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << "non-default Cyberdemon strength/hitpoints: " << c.getStrength() << "/" << c.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << "non-default Balrog strength/hitpoints: " << b.getStrength() << "/" << b.getHitpoints() << endl;

        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << "Examples of " << h.getSpecies() << " damage: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int damage = h.getDamage();
            cout << " Total damage = " << damage << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        cout << "Examples of " << e.getSpecies() << " damage: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int damage = e.getDamage();
            cout << " Total damage = " << damage << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        cout << "Examples of " << c.getSpecies() << " damage: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int damage = c.getDamage();
            cout << " Total damage = " << damage << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        cout << "Examples of " << b.getSpecies() << " damage: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int damage = b.getDamage();
            cout << " Total damage = " << damage << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;



    /*
        Elf e(50,50);
        Balrog b(50,50);


        battleArena(e, b);
    */

    }
```

Comment: Please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most of the code you show us is irrelevant to the problem. Also, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And edit your question to show us the expected output, as well as the actual output.

Comment: I think the problem is in `Demon demon(getStrength(), getHitpoints());` line in your `getDamage()` function in `class Demon`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the difference between your `creature` and `demon` class. Specifically at `getSpecies()`, that's where your issue is.

As a rule of thumb you should always use the `virtual` and `override` keywords when using inheritance to prevent bugs like these. They also make your code a lot more readable:

```
class Demon : public Creature
{
public:
      ....
      virtual string getSpecies() override
      {
        return "Demon";
      }
     ...
};
```

Do the same for your other classes, and your code should work as intended.

Comment: The `virtual` specifier isn't really needed, but using the `override` special identifier (it's not a keyword) is definitely good to use.

Comment: I've tried adding virtual and override but it doesn't get me the correct output. Balrog is still being named Demon.

Comment: @user9116941 Did you also add it in the `Balrog` class?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. Had to change Balrog's class from

```
int getDamage()
{
    //......        
    damage = balrog.getDamage();
    //......
}
```

to

```
int getDamage()
{
    //......          
    damage = Demon::getDamage();
    //......
}
```

Just a stupid mistake.